# unresolved dependencies (related to bintray sunset?)

Tags: scala, dependencies, bintray

I started getting an `unresolved dependency` error today across multiple jars.  I have no idea if it's related to the bintray sunset or something dumb on my end.

I got it working again, but I'm worried that's only because of some cached files.  If this is now broken, I need a long term solution.

**The dependency**

https://github.com/teralytics/geohex

You can see the indicated lines to include in `build.sbt`...

```
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("teralytics", "maven")

libraryDependencies += "net.teralytics" %% "geohex" % "0.1.+"
```

**My setup**

I have multiple fat jars that I push to Spark clusters...  they have a common dependency that I wrote, and I make available using `sbt publishLocal`.  Both the common dependency, and the final jars I push to Spark, all make heavy use of `geohex`.

I've always included `net.teralytics.geohex` refs in the `build.sbt` for both the underlying dependency and the final jars.  I do this for multiple references that are common across everything, and it's never been a problem.

Starting today (first time compiling since early June)...  the underlying jar compiled fine, but the downstream jars all failed to compile, throwing the following...

```
[warn]  module not found: net.teralytics#geohex_2.11;0.1.+
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/User123/.ivy2/local/net.teralytics/geohex_2.11/[revision]/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /Users/User123/.sbt/preloaded/net.teralytics/geohex_2.11/[revision]/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////Users/User123/.sbt/preloaded/net/teralytics/geohex_2.11/[revision]/geohex_2.11-[revision].pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/teralytics/geohex_2.11/[revision]/geohex_2.11-[revision].pom
[warn] ==== bintray-teralytics-maven: tried
[warn]   https://dl.bintray.com/teralytics/maven/net/teralytics/geohex_2.11/[revision]/geohex_2.11-[revision].pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: net.teralytics#geohex_2.11;0.1.+: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]    net.teralytics:geohex_2.11:0.1.+ (/Users/User123/jars/name123/build.sbt#L17-27)
[warn]      +- org.product123:name123.11:4.0.2
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: net.teralytics#geohex_2.11;0.1.+: not found

...

[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: net.teralytics#geohex_2.11;0.1.+: not found
```

Since I had `geohex` in the upstream jar, and that compiled fine, all I did was remove references to it from `build.sbt` for the downstream jars, and they compile now.

**But why?**

It looks like bintray has been sunsetted.  I read this...

https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/

but beyond copying the lines for `build.sbt` from github or mvnrepository...  I don't really understand what bintray does or if I'm in danger of losing access to geohex entirely because of these changes.

Did this work for now because I have some cached files on my laptop?

What's the best course of action?  Fork the repo and `publishLocal` to maintain availability?

Comment: The repository is still supposed to be reachable in read-only but I think the URL has changed. I don't have it right now unfortunately..

Comment: On the long term you should probably tell the maintainer (if the project is maintained) to publish to Sonatype OSSRH which then copy to Maven Central.

Answer (score 2):

The URL first hits maven central and then Bintray. As Bintray is sunset now, not sure now where exactly “teralytics” artifacts are hosted, you need to reach out to the maintainer of the project, The Github account https://github.com/teralytics.